# Overflow error in Python. Applying function to column of dates

Tags: python, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to a list of dates, however I keep getting an overflow error.

I've tried applying the function to individual cells, and even to the maximum of the column to see if that was the error. However that was not the error, and I don't quite know where to go now.

Here is my column from the data frame, Days_Until:

```
Index  Days
0     -50 days
1     -26 days
2      13 days
3     -53 days
4     -42 days
5     -22 days
6     -16 days
7      53 days
8     -57 days
9     -48 days
10    -40 days
11    -26 days
12    -22 days
13     14 days
14    -54 days
15    -47 days
16    -27 days
17     -1 days
18     18 days
19     42 days
20    -56 days
21    -53 days
22    -43 days
23    -30 days
24    -16 days
25     20 days
26    -54 days
27    -47 days
28    -40 days
29    -26 days
        ...   
704   -40 days
705   -51 days
706   -47 days
707   -44 days
708   -43 days
709   -44 days
710   -11 days
711    26 days
712    91 days
713   -52 days
714   -34 days
715   -54 days
716   -51 days
717    47 days
718   -50 days
719   -44 days
720   -28 days
721   -49 days
722   -41 days
723   -35 days
724   -34 days
725   -28 days
726   -20 days
727    41 days
728   -50 days
729    -8 days
730   -49 days
731    44 days
732   -43 days
733   -45 days
Name: time_weight_spt9, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Here is the function I want to apply to the column:

```
from math import pow
def exp_decay(days):
    days = getattr(days, "days", days)
    return pow(.5, (days/30.))
```

I know the function works, as I tested it on the maximum of Days_Until["Days"].

```
Days_Until["Days"].max()
>> 185

return pow(.5, (Days_Until["Days"].max()/30.))
>> 0.0139202924709
```

So I don't know why I get:

```
Days_Until["Days"].apply(exp_decay)
>> OverflowError: math range error
```

When I run the apply function on my column.

Suggestions?

As well, the min in -59, so I don't think that would have an effect on the result.

*** Edit ***

As furas suggested:

```
 from math import pow
 def exp_decay(days):
    print days
    days = getattr(days, "days", days)
    return pow(.5, (days/30.))
```

And now I get one line of output:

```
-4320000000000000 nanoseconds
```

And the same error:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

Are my days being read as nanoseconds?

Comment: add `print(days)` in `exp_decay` to see value which has problem.

Comment: Seems you are not passing all values for `apply` function correctly. [https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply)

Comment: it seems  `days` are kept in nanoseconds  :)  see also `timedelta64[ns]` in line `Name: time_weight_spt9, dtype: timedelta64[ns]`

Comment: Are you need to apply that function or you have something more complex? Because that you easy could do without apply function: `(Days_Until["Days"].dt.days/30).pow(.5))`

Comment: I tired that Anton, but I get this error: 
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Comment: @Chef1075 What `pandas` version are you using? Are you sure that your `Days_Until["Days"]` pandas Series with dtype `timedelta64[ns]`?

Comment: pd.__version__ = 0.17.1. However dtype is telling it is a numpy array. That seems like the problem.

Comment: Off course that's the problem, because `np.ndarray` doesn't have `dt` accessor. You could convert it to `timedelta` with `pd.to_timedelta`